# Load back submitted condition of an HTML form on page load

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a form whereby there is a `checkbox` and when I click on it, a `textbox` and `combobox` will appear

**Before click**

[image]

**After Click**

[image]

The codes are as below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pairingDiv").hide(); //This is hiding pairing item type div on page load   
  $("#currentItemDiv").hide(); // This is hiding the current item div on page load
});


$("#pairOrNotCheckBox").click(function() {
  if ($('#pairOrNotCheckBox:checkbox:checked').length > 0) { //This means user checked the 'Need to pair?' checkbox
    $("#pairingItem").val("");
    $("#pairingDiv").show();
    $("#currentItemDiv").show();
  } else { //User unchecked the 'Need to pair?' checkbox
    $("#pairingItem").val(""); //Clearing the pairing item drop down box
    $("#pairingDiv").hide(); //Hiding pairingDiv
    $("#currentItemDiv").hide(); //Hiding the currentitemDiv
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <label for="pairOrNotCheckBox" style="display: block; text-align:center;">Need to Pair?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="pairOrNotCheckBox" name="pairOrNotCheckBox">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2" id="currentItemDiv">
  <label for="currentItem">This Tag</label>
  <input type="textbox" class="form-control" id="currentItem" name="currentItem" readonly value="sample">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2" id="pairingDiv">
  <label for="pairingItem">Pairing Item</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="pairingItem" name="pairingItem">
    <option></option>
    <option>LO</option>
    <option>T</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Lets say I checked the checkbox and click on a save button, these data will be saved in database.

**What I need**

When someone load the page, with this particular data, I want the checkbox to be checked and all selections should retrieve from database. There is a variable `$paired` to track the status of `checkbox` from database. By using that, I modified the code as the following.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
                <label for="pairOrNotCheckBox" style="display: block; text-align:center;">Need to Pair?</label>
                  <?php
                    if($paired == 0){
                        echo '<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="pairOrNotCheckBox" name="pairOrNotCheckBox">';
                    }else{
                        echo '<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="pairOrNotCheckBox" name="pairOrNotCheckBox" checked=checked>';
                    }
                  ?>
                
              </div>
```

I can see `checkbox` is checked. But other two `div` and respective values not showing. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Actually the codes are more complicated with some `Ajax` function and all. But for demonstration purpose, I made it simple

**Edit 1**

To get a better overview, I will post some screenshots

When click on `checkbox`, it will show the following

[image]

Then when choose the `Pairing Item` option, `jQuery` will show hidden field and with `Ajax` call, it will populate next drop down menu

[image]

Choose next and `jQuery` show next drop down and another `Ajax` call populate items

[image]

Then when user press `save` button, all these values will be saved. I am trying to retrieve back all these by referring to `$paired` variable.

Comment: Of course they are not showing, you are explicitly hiding them on page load. So you will have to see if the checkbox is checked first, before you do that. And you will have to set the value for the text field and select the selected option as well, when you create those elements.

Comment: That is why I am setting the checkbox to checked based on the `$paired` condition. But although it is checked on page load, but other fields are not showing. Please see the **What I need** section carefully

Comment: You can set your checkbox to checked all you want, that doesn’t change the fact that the JS code you execute via `$(document).ready()` _hides_ those two elements, no matter what. And that’s _why I said_ (talk about reading carefully, hm?), you need to make _that part_ check whether your checkbox is checked or not, and only hide those elements if it isn’t.

Comment: @CBroe Got your point that by doing `checked=checked` won't help to execute `JS`. How can I proceed in this situation? My checking variable to set condition of `checkbox` is from `php` which is `$paired`.

Comment: In your click handler, you are already checking if the checkbox was checked or not. So what is stopping you from doing the same thing in your `$(document).ready()` handler then?